# Simple jQuery element html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile-nav').click(function() {
        if($(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>')){
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>');
        } else {
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
        }

    });

});
```

When you first click on it, the html content changes as I expect, but when I click again the `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>` are not set again.

What I'm doing wrong?

-----------------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

After reading these helpful answers and combining them into one the answer for this should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile-nav').click(function() {
      if ($('i', this).hasClass("fa-bars")) {
          $('i', this).removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-times");
      } else {
          $('i', this).removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-bars");
      }
    });    
});
```

Comment: @Huangism actually, it will return true. Just sayin'

Comment: yea it will return true I was pointing at the logic but the logic seems to be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check it like that, check the class name. Not to mention you're setting the HTML, not checking it.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("fa-bars")) {
    $(this).removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-times");
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-bars");
}
```

Comment: Or : `$(this).toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times')`

Comment: `if ($('i', this).hasClass("fa-bars")) {`?

Comment: but fa-bars is actually content it comes from FontAwesome, if I do with classes I will have to set the content on css?

Comment: That worked @RUJordan, setting as correct answer in 5 minutes, I'm not allowed yet. On that code though if someone else read this the element to apply the function on should be $('#mobile-nav i')
Thank you!

Comment: Actually the code should be like this
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile-nav').click(function() {
      if ($('#mobile-nav i').hasClass("fa-bars")) {
          $('#mobile-nav i').removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-times");
      } else {
          $('#mobile-nav i').removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-bars");
      }
    });    
});`

Comment: @Jaypee actually, it shouldn't, because you're unnecessarily repeating the `#mobile-nav` selector.  You should cache a reference to `$('i', this)` in the start of the handler and then use that everywhere else.

Comment: @Alnitak you're right man, learned a lot of things today with all these great answers and explanations. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This condition in the predicate:

```
$(this).html(...)
```

always returns `$(this)`, which is "truthy", so only the first part of the branch is ever taken.

In any event (no pun intended) you should never test the serialised version of the HTML to maintain state.  You could check for a specific class (`.hasClass`) or use data attributes (`.data`) stored on the element, or a variable bound in the lexical scope, e.g.:

```
(function() {
    var state = false;
    $('#mobile-nav').on('click', function() {
       state = !state;
       if (state) {
           ...
       } else {
           ...
       }
    });
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class if it is not present:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2700/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mobile-nav li').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('fa-bars')) {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-bars');
            $(this).addClass('fa-times');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-times');
            $(this).addClass('fa-bars');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` was deprecated

Comment: @Alnitak - Could you provide the documentation that states that it was depcrated.  That would be helpful.

Comment: i dont get it what you want.. You mean sample code for the same?

Comment: @CodeMaverick http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/   The version that toggles the visibility of an element still exists, though.

Comment: @Alnitak - Sorry about that, I had the wrong toggle method linked. It's updated.

Comment: in jQuery 1.8 library